# Divergent succession, but with convergent sum average.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, cesaro-summable

An example of a sequence $a_n$ such that:
$$a_n\rightarrow\pm\infty$$ but $$b_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n}$$ converge.

Answer (score 2):

Assume without loss of generality that $a_n > 0$ always. Suppose that $b_n \to L$ a finite limit. Since $a_n \to \infty$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have that $a_n > 2L$. But then for $n > 2N$,
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_n > 0 + \sum_{k = N}^{n} 2L > Ln.$$
So in particular, the average of these terms will always be more than $L$, contrary to the claim. This is a contradiction. $\diamondsuit$

More generally, it's true that if $a_n \to L$, then the average value of $a_n$ also converges to $L$.

---

To match the edit, consider
$$ a_n = (-1)^n \log n. $$

Comment: can you please explain the last part of the inequality?

Comment: If $n > 2N$, then we have at least $N$ terms at least $2L$ in size.

Comment: that is true if $a_n>0$,  but if $a_n=(-1)^nn^\alpha$ with $\alpha$  
suitable ?

Comment: @AlexanderOsorio We know that $a_n \to \infty$. If necessary, we prepad the indices by sufficiently many terms so that the initial sum is positive. It is not possible for the terms to alternate in sign arbitrarily long.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not clear about your explanation. But I think $a_n = \sqrt n$ is a counterexample, Where the average is convergent.

Comment: @ShoumanDas I don't know what you mean. The sum of the first $N$ terms of the sequence $\sqrt n$ is about $N^{3/2}$. So the average of the first $N$ terms is about $\sqrt N$, which clearly goes to $\infty$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks. But if we relax the condition to $|a_n| \to \infty$, can we get any counterexample?

Comment: Sure. Take something like $(-1)^n\log n$. Roughly speaking, since $\log (n+1) - \log n \approx 0$ for large $n$, you'll get $b_n \to 0$.

Comment: $a_n\rightarrow\infty$ means  $a_n\rightarrow+\infty$ or $a_n\rightarrow-\infty$ or both. That is, a particular case might be an alternating series.

Comment: @AlexanderOsorio I have never used that notation or seen that notation used in that way. If the OP means unstandard notation like that, it should be clarified.